# Linux Device Driver Access Control

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am implementing a device driver for some novel hardware, and want to only allow one process to have access to the device at a time.  Concurrent read/write operations would confuse the hardware to the point where a hard reset would more than likely need to occur.  I still have the following questions:

1. In the example code [from *Linux Device Drivers*](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch05s06.html) , the `open()` call uses a lock, but `close()` does not.  Isn't there still a race condition here, or is the decrement of `scull_s_count` guaranteed to be atomic?  Basically, in this example, I'm wondering what would happen if one process is trying to open the device right when another process is wrapping up and closing it.
2. I'm assuming that I do not need to check the status of my open flag (I'm doing something similar to the example's `scull_s_count`) in my `read()` and `write()` calls, since the only way to get into these calls is if the userspace application already has received the `fd` via a successful call to `open()`.  Is that assumption correct?

Thanks to tadman's comments, I did the most cursory search of the kernel's `atomic_t` mechanisms. Here's some pseudo-code of what I have now:

```
int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
  spin_lock(&lock);
  if (atomic_read(&open_flag)) {
    spin_unlock(&lock);
    return -EBUSY;
  }
  atomic_set(&open_flag, 1);
  /* do other open() related stuff */
  spin_unlock(&lock);
  return 0;
}

int close(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
  int rc;
  /* do close() stuff */
  atomic_set(&open_flag, 0);
  return rc;
}
```

The `open_flag` is an `atomic_t` that is part of a larger struct that is allocated with `kzalloc()`.  As a result, it gets initialized to zero.

As a result, the code here shows that the lock's purpose is to prevent multiple processes/threads from opening the device at the same time, while the fact that the `open_flag` is an `atomic_t` prevents the race condition I was concerned about in question 1 above.  Does this implementation suffice?  Also, I am still looking for an answer to question 2.

The example code uses a spinlock, but would a mutex be more appropriate?  The section of code is relatively small and there is little to no contention, so going to sleep and waking up might have less performance than just spinning.  The lock/mutex is always accessed from the user context, so you should be safe to sleep.

Comment: If you have an atomic flag you won't have race conditions.

Comment: Is there a POSIX atomic flag?  I know of std::atomic_flag from C++11, but this is a Linux Device Driver written in C.

Comment: Even a cursory search for atomic operations in the kernel gives [results like this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/core-api/atomic_ops.html).

Comment: Thanks. Converting my flag over to an atomic_t now.  Going to post example code here shortly.

Comment: @tadman, take a look at my updated question if you have the time.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: That's good work coming up with a snippet. I'm not sure I could confidently answer if that's 100% okay, so I'll leave it unanswered, but I think anyone with recent kernel experience would be able to judge now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you point to is indeed flawed.  The decrement is absolutely not guaranteed to be atomic and almost certainly will not be.

But realistically, I don't think there is a compiler/CPU combination that would ever produce code that could fail.  The worst that could happen is one CPU core could finish the close, then another core could call open and  get back busy because it has a stale cached value of the flag.

Linux provides `atomic_*` functions for this and also `*_bit` atomic bit flag operations.  See core_api/atomic_ops.rst in the kernel documentation.

A example of a correct and simple pattern to do his would look something like:

```
unsigned long mydriver_flags;
#define IN_USE_BIT 0

static int mydriver_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
        if (test_and_set_bit(IN_USE_BIT, &mydriver_flags))
                return -EBUSY;
        /* continue with open */
        return 0;
}

static int mydriver_close(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
        /* do close stuff first */
        smp_mb__before_atomic();
        clear_bit(IN_USE_BIT, &mydriver_flags);
        return 0;
}
```

A real driver should have a device state struct, for each device, with `mydriver_flags` in it.  Rather than using a single global for the whole driver as shown in the example.

That said, what you are trying to do is probably not a good idea.  Even if only one *process* can open the device at a time, a process' open file descriptors are shared amongst all *threads* in the process.  Multiple threads can make simultaneous `read()` and `write()` calls to the same file descriptor.

If a process has a file descriptor open and calls `fork()`, that descriptor will be inherited into the new process.  This is a way multiple *processes* can have the device open at once despite the above "single open" restriction.

So you still have to be thread safe in your driver's file operations since a user can still have multiple threads/processes open the device at once and make simultaneous calls.  And if you've made it safe, why prevent the user from doing it?  Maybe they know what they're doing and will insure their multiple openers of the driver will "take turns" and not make calls that conflict?

Also consider the possibility using the O_EXCL flag in the open call to make single open optional.

Comment: So I looked over the code and there are other mechanisms in place to prevent a shared fd from doing a simultaneous read/write.  I guess the real problem I was trying to solve was multiple processes each getting access to the device with their own fds, and I think what I have implemented prevents that.

Comment: That can still happen, as there's a possible race between atomic_read and atomic_set in your open handler. You need to use one of the atomic operations that sets and returns the value.

Comment: @domen, Sorry I don't see the race, can you elaborate?

Comment: There wasn't really a race, since the lock protected the non-atomic check-then-set in open().  But it sort of defeated the purpose of atomic ops to use them non-atomically and then fix that with a spin lock.

Comment: Apologies, no race. I agree with TrentP.

Comment: `The decrement is absolutely not guaranteed to be atomic` wrong, you can't call close on an invalid file handle and the open make sure only one process get it

Comment: The decrement being atomic or not is not based on how many processes can be running the code at once.  As I said in my answer, the race could occur if one process were to call open after another calls close, one can not be assured the view of the flag will be ordered between those two actions.

Comment: If the driver is already opened any other open will fail, there's no race, you just need to set the flag last in the close implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You and the others who have provided answers are all correct that the example is flawed, and TrentP is correct that you don't need a lock at all if you use atomic bit operations like `test_and_set_bit()` (or you could use `atomic_add_unless()`, etc).

However, his answer is also not completely correct, because it does not take care of instruction reordering in the `close()` - `clear_bit()` does not include a memory barrier.  Thus, setting the variable to zero could happen before the "do close stuff", which would likely totally mess up the driver if someone else opens it at the same time.  A fixed solution adds a barrier before the call to `clear_bit`:

```
static unsigned long mydriver_flags;
#define IN_USE_BIT 0

static int mydriver_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
        if (test_and_set_bit(IN_USE_BIT, &mydriver_flags))
                return -EBUSY;
        /* continue with open */
        return 0;
}

static int mydriver_close(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
        /* do close stuff first */
        smp_mb_before_atomic();
        clear_bit(IN_USE_BIT, &mydriver_flags);
        return 0;
}
```

Note that `test_and_set_bit()` is fully ordered and already implies the memory barriers, so the `open()` function needs no change.

Now to answer your actual questions:

1. Yes, there is race condition and the decrement is not atomic.  Many bad things could happen if one process is trying to open the device whilst another is closing it.  For example, part of your cleanup code might run at the same time as your device initialisation code from the concurrent open, which could lead to almost any nasty outcome imaginable.
2. Yes, your assumption is correct.  You do not need any checks in your read/write methods.

### Additional notes:

- The code shown in the question does not suffice because there is no ordering in `close()`; you need a `smp_mb_before_atomic()` before the `atomic_set()` in `close()`, similar to the code above.  But the lock is not required if you simply combine the atomic read and set by using `test_and_set_bit()` as shown above and by TrentP.
- spinlock vs mutex: the decision is very simply guided by whether you need to sleep under the lock, i.e. if your initialization code contains anything that might result in sleeping of the process, then you should use a mutex, whilst if your initialisation just sets up some variables and then drops the lock again, then a spinlock is perfectly sensible as it is more lightweight than a mutex.  Given this is your open/close, i.e. nothing performance critical, it would be perfectly fine to just use a mutex and not worry about whether the code might sleep or not.  However, the code is much better if you just throw away the lock altogether and just use the `test_and_set_bit()` as shown.

Comment: It is copied yes but it is also corrected and I said so.  Please read the paragraph above the code block where I say that TrentP's answer is not correct with the explanation why and that a "fixed solution would be" and then quoted the same code block but with the correction.  Surely it is better to do that than to say "Please look at TrentP's code block and insert smp_mb_before_atomic() on line 13 (or which ever line number it is."?

Comment: I don't think copying someone else's answer to change one line of code is accepted practice on SO.  You make a comment to the answer in that case.

Comment: That seems a bit silly to me but fair enough.  However, I did also answer all the OP's questions unlike anyone else did so it would have been weird to do that in a comment.  It would also seem silly to provide answers to his questions and then separately make a comment correcting your answer (and your answer is plain wrong without the memory barrier I put in it!) And it would have been a total waste of time to rewrite the answer from scratch.  And I did reference that the answer shown is from you so I really do not see the issue...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rust on linux kernel programming but, using both atomic and the spinlock looks a bit of an overhead to me.

> want to only allow one process to have access to the device at a time

And if that is what you need the scull implementation works just fine, the spinlock within the open implemetation of the scull driver make sure only one process get a valid file handle at a time.

<strike>I think</strike> I'm pretty sure (didn't check) the skull example don't use the lock in the release (close) because only the process that opened it can close it, other process wouldn't get within the release code if the file handle isn't valid.

> The example code uses a spinlock, but would a mutex be more appropriate?

The spinlock implementation is faster and enough for this task.

```
int scull_s_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
  scull_s_count--; /* release the device */

  /* from there until the function return is the only place where a race can occur
  *  so I wouldn't define the scull implementation "flawed" */

  MOD_DEC_USE_COUNT;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A spinlock is at it's heart a looping call to an atomic test-and-set primitive that runs until it succeeds.  So it's unlikely a spinlock protecting a non-atomic test then set would be faster than an atomic test-and-set, as the spin effectively contains the atomic test-and-set plus a bit more.  In the same manner, a mutex is contains a spinlock that protects the operation of the mutex.  If the code protected in a spinlock is less than the code to implement a mutex, it's more efficient to use the spinlock.

Comment: @TrentP the question was mutex or spinlock, not spinlock or atomic. Beside, if only used for open the performance of some millisec is irrelevant

Answer (score 1):

> want to only allow one process to have access to the device at a time

You can't: `fork()` make it impossible to prevent one device to be opened by a single process, because after fork() the child inherit the file descriptors from its parent, allowing both parent and child to read/write/ioctl the device. Also `exec()` will transfer the file descriptor for your device to another program.

And don't forget Unix socket can be used to pass the file descriptor to your device to another process (see `SCM_RIGHTS`).

Answer (score -1):

You're looking at the problem wrong.  If the hardware can't handle concurrent reads/writes, then it's up to the driver to enforce that.  The driver is the single process that has access to the hardware.  The driver is allowing access to itself in a thread-safe manner.  The read/writes from userspace shouldn't go directly to the hardware, they should be handled by the driver, and the driver deals with the hardware however the hardware requires.  For example, the write() handler can just dump the data into a queue and set a flag, so that your write_hardware infinite loop can take it and actually write it to the hardware when it's ok to do so.

Comment: See my comment in Trent's answer.  There are other mechanisms in place to deal with concurrent read/write.  What's bothersome currently is that two processes can open the device at the same time, which makes no sense to do, since Process A can read some data and Process B can read another set of data.  I need to prevent that since a single process needs a continuous stream of data until it is totally done with the device and calls close().

Comment: That wasn't the question you asked.